# Groupby and plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with multiple rows for a same date. For example:

```
date        col1    col2
1854-11-09  314.2   567.9
1854-11-17  322.8   678.9
1854-11-17  432.8   435.0
1854-11-21  678.9   476.2
1854-11-21  872.7   892.0
1854-11-21  656.9   490.2
1854-11-21  278.9   586.8
```

I want to plot graphs for individual dates for the last two columns. For example: there will a x-y graph with one point for the 1st date. For the 2nd date there will be 2 points (2 x-axis data, 2 y-axis data), for the 3rd date 4 data points and so on.

I tried groupby but it is not working.

I am also confused about the best way to potray such result because there are two many dates, any suggestion on that front is also welcome.

Comment: I am assuming : you want the plots for last two columns with respect to date, and so you want X-axis representing individual dates and Y axis representing the last two columns?

Comment: No, the x and y axis should be the last two columns respectively but one plot for each day.  Date should be the grouping criteria.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Could you tell me about the number of unique dates?

Comment: Almost 7 years of data, hence the last sentence of my question!

Comment: Assuming you have 3 columns named : `date`, `col1`,`col2`. One way to approach this problem is to have the X-axis as `col1` and Y axis as `col2`. Moreover, the `date` could be represented in the same graph by using different colours. Since you have 7 years of data, you could create one plot for one month or one year according to your preference. This can reduce the number of graphs from plotting for each unique date entries to months or years. Does this help?

Comment: Actually it depends on which year to be considered, because for some days there is a lot more data for a particular year other years are pretty empty. Anyway that can be solved later but do you have a code snippet to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution  might work for you.

Convert your data into a dataframe using pandas, this is how it should look:

```
    date          x      y
0   1854-11-09  314.2   567.9
1   1854-11-17  322.8   678.9
2   1854-11-17  432.8   435.0
3   1854-11-21  678.9   476.2
4   1854-11-21  872.7   892.0
```

Then use groupby by 'date' and for each group values use matplotlib's scatter plot to plot the x-y coordinates or points.

```
for group, values in data.groupby(data['date']):
        plt.scatter(values['x'], values['y'], c ='r')
        plt.show()
```

Finally, this is how the plot will look like:

[image]